# Is it possible to rebind the key that opens the Windows printscreen snip tool?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

By default, the Windows printscreen snip tool is bound to the incredibly inconvenient <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key combination. However, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key combination is still completely free since its functionality for some bizarre reason is bound to the exact same as the regular printscreen button. Apparently the shift-key is a joke to Windows or something.

My question therefore is, is there *any* possibility to re-bind this Windows snip tool to a sensible key combination like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>? I wouldn't mind if I had to install an extra tool (although if not needed I'd prefer not to). I have also tried tools like gyazo but I don't like that that can't re-bind itself to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>, and I don't like that it automatically uploads my screenshots to the internet instead of simply copying it to my clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to do this with the following code:

```
+PrintScreen::Send #+s
```

Explanation:

- `+` means <kbd>Shift</kbd> and `#` means <kbd>Win</kbd>
- `+PrintScreen::` looks for you pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>
- `Send #+s` sends the keypresses <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>

It looks like you can also do this using the [Keyboard Manager PowerToy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) from Microsoft, although I've not tried this.